# Is there any known suggestion for 32 operations version of "Squares: A Fast Counter-Based RNG"?

Tags: random-seed

At proposal Squares: A Fast Counter-Based RNG [Paper of: Squares: A Fast Counter-Based RNG, by Bernard Widynski](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.06278.pdf)

coded [Git Hub: Squares: A Fast Counter-Based RNG (Random Number Generator)](https://github.com/FlorisSteenkamp/squares-rng/tree/master)

it includes 64 bit operations only with 4 or 5 rounds - does someone know of a similar suggestion with 32 bit operations and yet producing satisfactory result (passing same random criteria as mentioned there), and still competitive with Philox of 10 rounds?